# Getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when unit testing with mongodb-memory-server

Tags: typescript, mongodb, unit-testing, mongoose, jestjs

I am trying to unit test some typescript logic with [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest). I am using [mongoose](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose) in order to interact with the mongo database and [mongo-memory-server](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server) in order to mock mongodb.

For unclear reason, I get the following error, which seems to result from cyclic dependencies, when running the below unit test.

Error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:38:3)
      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:38:3)
```

Unit Test:

```
import mongoose, { Mongoose } from "mongoose";
import { MongoMemoryServer } from "mongodb-memory-server";

describe("test mongo memory server", () => {
    let client: Mongoose;
    let mongod;

    beforeAll(async () => {
      mongod = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
      client = await mongoose.connect(mongod.getUri());
    });

    afterAll(async () => {

      if (mongod) {
        await mongod.stop();
      }
    });

    it("empty test", async () => {
    });
});
```

Used Versions in `package.json`:

```
...  "dependencies": {
        "typescript": "4.6.3",
        "mongoose": "6.2.9", // required for mongo 5.0
     },
     "devDependencies": {
        "jest": "27.5.1",
        "mongodb-memory-server": "8.4.2",
     }
```

P.S:

1. When commenting out the connection to mongo (`client = await mongoose.connect(mongod.getUri());`), and using `mongo-memory-server` (version: 7.6.3) the below unit test passes. On the other hand, when the line is not commented out, it fails.
2. When commenting out the connection to mongo (`client = await mongoose.connect(mongod.getUri());`), but using latest `mongo-memory-server`, version 8.4.2 - the test fails.

Comment: I'm also getting the same error message when I try to test a route with jest. Did you have any luck solving this issue?

Answer (score 1):

For me it was some errors in my `jest.config.js`. I had this line in it:

```js
moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "src"],
```

When I commented it out, the error message stopped appearing.

Answer (score 0):

I've been facing the same issue today, I just removed node_modules and package-lock.json, npm install'ed and the issue was gone.
Take care.

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately it didn't help...