# "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when trying to use Jest with Mongoose and MongoMemoryServer

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, express, ts-jest

I'm trying to test my express app using Jest. Anytime I run my test I get the following error that is somehow connected to MongoDB but I can't figure out what exactly I have to do to solve this problem:

```
 FAIL  src/routes/__test__/signUp.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:39:3)
      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:39:3)
      at Object.get [as ObjectId] (node_modules/mongodb/src/bson.ts:39:3)
```

Here is the test:

```
import request from 'supertest';
import { app } from 'app';

it('Returns a 201 on successful signup', async () => {
  return request(app)
    .post('/api/users/signup')
    .send({
      email: 'test@test.com',
      password: 'password',
    })
    .expect(201);
});
```

I also have some setup for my tests, maybe the problem is hiding somewhere here:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';

let mongo: MongoMemoryServer;

beforeAll(async () => {
  process.env.JWT_KEY = 'whateverfornow';

  mongo = await MongoMemoryServer.create();
  const mongoUri = mongo.getUri();

  await mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {});
});

beforeEach(async () => {
  const collections = await mongoose.connection.db.collections();

  for (let collection of collections) {
    await collection.deleteMany({});
  }
});

afterAll(async () => {
  if (mongo) {
    await mongo.stop();
  }

  await mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" when unit testing with mongodb-memory-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71743639/getting-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-when-unit-testing-with-mo)